# Using rule of inference to deduce conclusion

Tags: discrete-mathematics

(a) ~*q*

(b) (*p* v *r*) --> *q*

(c) ~*p*

(d) ~*r* --> (*m* v *b*)

(e) *b* --> ~*f*

(f) *f*

(g) (~*p* ^ *m*) --> *n*

(h) (~*p* ^ *b*) --> *k*

```
1. ~(p v r)  by modus tollens (b, a)
2. ~p ^ ~r   by DeMorgan's Law (1)
3. ~r        by '^' Elimination (2)
4. m v b     by modus ponens (3, d)
5. ~b v ~f   by definition of a conditional "or"
6. f
```

This was as far as I could go. I had another solution, but my question for this was for lines 5 and 6, can they somehow deduce to something that uses the 'v' elimination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't deduce $f$, you already know $f$, it's (f).

---

Modus tollens on (e) $:b\to\neg f$ and (f) $:f$ , gives $:\neg b$

This and (4) $: m\vee b$, gives $: m$

That and (c) $: \neg p$, gives $: m\wedge \neg p$

Then modus ponens with (g) and you can take it from there.

Comment: Thank you for your help! That's where I was stumbling: using modus tallness on (e) and (f).